# Storing line number in ANTLR Parse Tree

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr4, grammar, line-numbers

Is there any way of storing line numbers in the created parse tree, using ANTLR 4? I came across [this](http://puredanger.github.io/tech.puredanger.com/2007/02/01/recovering-line-and-column-numbers-in-your-antlr-ast/) article, which does it but I think it's for older ANTLR version, because

> parser.setASTFactory(factory);

It does not seem to be applicable to ANTLR 4.
I am thinking of having something like

> treenode.getLine()

, like we can have

> treenode.getChild()

Answer (score 3):

With Antlr4, you normally implement either a listener or a visitor.

Both give you a context where you find the location of the tokens.

For example (with a visitor), I want to keep the location of an assignment defined by a Uppercase identifier (UCASE_ID in my token definition).

The bit you're interested in is ...

```
ctx.UCASE_ID().getSymbol().getLine()
```

The visitor looks like ...

```
static class TypeAssignmentVisitor extends ASNBaseVisitor<TypeAssignment> {
    @Override
    public TypeAssignment visitTypeAssignment(TypeAssignmentContext ctx) {
        String reference = ctx.UCASE_ID().getText();
        int line = ctx.UCASE_ID().getSymbol().getLine();
        int column = ctx.UCASE_ID().getSymbol().getCharPositionInLine()+1;

        Type type = ctx.type().accept(new TypeVisitor());
        TypeAssignment typeAssignment = new TypeAssignment();
        typeAssignment.setReference(reference);
        typeAssignment.setReferenceToken(new Token(ctx.UCASE_ID().getSymbol().getLine(), ctx.UCASE_ID().getSymbol().getCharPositionInLine()+1));
        typeAssignment.setType(type);
        return typeAssignment;
    }
}
```

I was new to Antlr4 and found this useful to get started with listeners and visitors ...
https://github.com/JakubDziworski/AntlrListenerVisitorComparison/