# How to enter the code line numbers to parseTree in antlr

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, line-numbers

I am generating the parseTree for the Javascript Code using the antlr grammer. Is there a way to add line numbers to the parse tree using the antlr.?

```
     String a = "function a(){\n" +
                "            var a =10;\n" +
                "            if(a>20){\n" +
                "                a=a+1;\n" +
                "            }else{\n" +
                "                a=a-1;\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        }";
       try{
            CharStream charStream = CharStreams.fromString(a);
            JavaScriptLexer javaScriptLexer =new JavaScriptLexer(charStream);
            CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(javaScriptLexer);
            JavaScriptParser javaScriptParser = new JavaScriptParser(commonTokenStream);
            ParseTree parseTree = javaScriptParser.program();
            System.out.println(parseTree.toStringTree(javaScriptParser));


        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

This Code gives the output

```
(program (sourceElements (sourceElement (statement (functionDeclaration function a ( ) { (functionBody (sourceElements (sourceElement (statement (variableStatement (varModifier var) (variableDeclarationList (variableDeclaration a = (singleExpression (literal (numericLiteral 10))))) (eos ;)))) (sourceElement (statement (ifStatement if ( (expressionSequence (singleExpression (singleExpression a) > (singleExpression (literal (numericLiteral 20))))) ) (statement (block { (statementList (statement (expressionStatement (expressionSequence (singleExpression (singleExpression a) = (singleExpression (singleExpression a) + (singleExpression (literal (numericLiteral 1)))))) (eos ;)))) })) else (statement (block { (statementList (statement (expressionStatement (expressionSequence (singleExpression (singleExpression a) = (singleExpression (singleExpression a) - (singleExpression (literal (numericLiteral 1)))))) (eos ;)))) }))))))) })))) <EOF>)
```

I need to add line numbers to the parseTree along with the other details. I wanna know how is there a way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing line number in ANTLR Parse Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630314/storing-line-number-in-antlr-parse-tree)

Comment: @AlexBroadwin not worked for me looking for perfect answer

Comment: Which ANTLR version, 3 or 4?

Comment: antlr 4 @JiriTousek